# Conditional type checking of Dart does not work as expected

Tags: dart, typechecking

I have two related classes: **Animal** and **Cat** (which extends **Animal**) then I make an instance of **Cat** and check if the instance is type **Cat** so I set amount of paws to four.

```
abstract class Animal {
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  int? pawsAmount;
}

void main(List<String> arguments) async {

  Animal barsik = Cat();

  if (barsik is Cat) {
    barsik.pawsAmount = 4;
  }

}
```

and it works well BUT the follow code is not:

```
abstract class Animal {
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  int? pawsAmount;
}


class Consumer {

  Animal _animal;

  Consumer(Animal animal) : _animal = animal;

  void init() {
    if (_animal is Cat) {
      _animal.pawsAmount = 4;
    }
  }

}

void main(List<String> arguments) async {

  Animal barsik = Cat();

  if (barsik is Cat) {
    barsik.pawsAmount = 4;
  }

  final consumer = Consumer(barsik);
  consumer.init();

}
```

it has got an error:

```
bin/constest.dart:17:15: Error: The setter 'pawsAmount' isn't defined for the class 'Animal'.
 - 'Animal' is from 'bin/constest.dart'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'pawsAmount'.
      _animal.pawsAmount = 4;
              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

if I change

```
if (_animal is Cat) {
  _animal.pawsAmount = 4;
}
```

to

```
if (_animal is Cat) {
  (_animal as Cat).pawsAmount = 4;
}
```

it works fine

#### Is there any way to make the code work?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there is the same question.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart only promotes *local* variables.
The `_animal` is an instance variable, which means that it can potentially change value at any time (the compiler won't start trying to predict whether it actually does), and therefore you can't promote it - the value might change between the check and the later use, making the check an insufficient guarantee.

I would move the value into a local variable before checking it:

```dart
  void init() {
    var animal = _animal;
    if (animal is Cat) {
      animal.pawsAmount = 4;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if I make _animal 'final' the problem will exist

Comment: It doesn't matter if the variable is `final` or not. It could be overridden by a getter in a derived class.

Comment: There is no way to make the compiler believe that a non-local variable won't change. In many cases, there are non-obvious ways it could fail. Even if it's a final static variable, which surely cannot change, allowing you to promote that variable would make it a breaking change to change the variable to a getter. Because of that, you cannot promote non-local variables.